# How can send audio file to FireBase in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-storage

I want to upload recorded audio to FireBase storage, but even though I have not worked for a long time, I still working for this.

I seemed to have three options; upload with API, upload with FireBase, upload with socket.

I tried the first two options, but I did not get a nice result.

Finally, I tried the second option. I’ve successfully sent the audio file to FireBase. But the file looks bad, It can’t play.

Here is the my code for this;

DataProvider.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import { DateTime } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class DataProvider {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private storage: AngularFireStorage) {

  }

  uploadToStorage(blob, metadata): AngularFireUploadTask {
    let newName = new Date().getTime() + '.mp3';

    return this.storage.ref('files/' + newName).put(blob);
  }

}
```

Post.ts:

```
doPost() {
    const metadata = {
      contentType: 'audio/mp3',
    };
    const file = { dir: this.navParams.get('fileDir') }
    console.log('Dir:' + file.dir);
    var blob = new Blob([file.dir], { type: 'audio/mp3' });

    let upload = this.dataProvider.uploadToStorage(blob, metadata);

    upload.then().then(res => {
      console.log('res: ', res);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Hey friend, did you manage to solve this? I am in the same situation here.

Comment: @franzmobile Hey there I resolved that with a backend service to .net. I used naudio .net for that

Answer (score 0):

> In TS ----
>
> ```
> onFileChanged(param){
>    var aa;
>    const file: File = param.target.files[0];
>    const metaData = { 'contentType': file.type };
>    const StorageRef: firebase.storage.Reference = firebase.storage().ref('/photos/Category/'+this.CategoryName);
>    const Store = StorageRef.put(file, metaData);
>
>    setTimeout((enter code here) => {
>      const UP: firebase.storage.UploadTask = Store;
>      UP.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function (downloadURL) {
>        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
>        aa = downloadURL;
>      });
>     }, 1000);
>
>     setTimeout(() => {
>       this.ImageLink = aa;
>       debugger;
>     }, 2000);
>
>  }
> ```
>
> import * as firebase from '@ionic/firebase
>
> In HTML :

Comment: <input id="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" type="file"  #file style="display: none">
   <img (click)="file.click()" style="margin-left: 10%"src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/512/Photo-Video-Stack-Of-Photos-icon.png" width="50px" />